# Вывести таблицу

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
function Add(){
    $("#red_sk").append("<table border=\"1\">");
    $("#red_sk").append("<tr>&nbsp;");

    for(var i=1; i < 10; i++){

        $("#red_sk").append('<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>');

        switch (i){
            case 3: $("#red_sk").append("</tr>\n"); break;
            case 6: $("#red_sk").append("</tr>\n"); break;
            case 9: $("#red_sk").append("</tr>\n"); break;
        }
    }

    $("#red_sk").append("</table>");
}
```

Должно получится

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**В чём ошибка ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
function Add(){
    var tabl = '';
    tabl+="<table border=\"1\">";
    tabl+="<tr>&nbsp;";

    for(var i=1; i < 10; i++){

        tabl+='<td><input type="button" id="cn'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>';

        switch (i){
            case 3: tabl+="</tr>\n"; break;
            case 6: tabl+="</tr>\n"; break;
            case 9: tabl+="</tr>\n"; break;
        }
    }
    tabl+="</table>";
    $("#red_sk").append(tabl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас добавление строк таблицы идет после добавления таблицы, а не внутрь ее. 
Функция append отличается от innerHTML.